# Save checkbox selected value to database PHP

Tags: php

I have developed a program to save the checked value of the checkbox to the database.

The selected value is not passing to the database properly. There are no syntax errors in the code.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123456", "database");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>

<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label>  <br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{//to run PHP script on submit
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list']))
        {
            foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected)
                {
                    if(isset($_POST['PHP'])) {
                $stmt = $link->prepare('INSERT INTO `checkbox` (`php_value`) VALUES ($selected)');
                        $stmt->bind_param('s', $stmt);
                        $stmt->execute();

                    }



} // if(isset($_POST['submit']))

    mysqli_close($link);
                }
        }


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST['PHP']` doesn't exist to be checked, that's why checkbox values don't save to database.

**Changed:**

```
if(isset($_POST['PHP']))
```

**With:**

```
 if($selected!="") {
```

**Updated Code:**

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123456", "database");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label>  <br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{//to run PHP script on submit
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
            if($selected!="") {
                $stmt = $link->prepare('INSERT INTO `checkbox` (`php_value`) VALUES (?)');
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $selected);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }

        mysqli_close($link);
    }
}


?>
```

Also added proper indentation for readability.

Comment: Hey, @Karlo Kokkak Thanks for your answer. It's working now. but there is a slight issue that the same checkbox value saved twice in the table. Any clue?

Comment: Code works when tested locally. I posted an update anyways.

Comment: Thank you so much @Karlo Kokkak. All good now. one more question tho. What I need to do is keep the checkbox checked after it's been checked by a user. I am going to implement a login interface for this and if someone checked the checkbox,  it should be shown to all the other users as well. Any suggestion how to do that?

Comment: I am out of words to thank you fam. Literally, you saved my life. It's working fine now. Wow, you're a living legend! God bless you my man! <3 @Karlo Kokkak

Comment: Hey as a gratitude towards the help you gave me I upvoted some of your questions & answers. :) @Karlo Kokkak

Comment: Serial voting is not allowed. It's reversed. Thanks anyways. :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167777/discussion-between-izu-and-karlo-kokkak).